# Работа с файлами, запуск файла программой по умолчанию

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать код, который бы допустим открыл одну из песен формата .mp3 и воспроизвел его в допустим vlc. Вопрос заключается в том, как примерно пишется нечто подобное на java. Цель : допустим есть много песен в папке, хочу считать их и выбрать рандомно одну, и запустить ее через программу которая для данного формата поставлена по умолчанию (например vlc, если это mp3)

Answer (score 1):

[`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:/randomSong.mp3"));`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

Answer (score 1):

```
File directory = new File("C:\\music");
Files[] files = directory.listFiles();

if(files != null && files.length > 0) {
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int fileNum = rnd.nextInt(files.length);

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(files[fileNum]);
}
```